# How to instant filter an array of objects based on the user's input

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

This was supposed to be easy, but it honestly got me scratching my head for some reason.

Basically I am querying data from firestore into my main component, and I am filtering this data based on the users input.

The thing is my search functionality is located in another component, so I am passing the queried data as component props to the search component, and I am trying to filter it based on the user's input.

If a User for example types 'S', it should show all the items that start with S, then, 'SP' narrows it down, etc.

I am not sure if it is a good idea to do that or create another query and filter it straight from the Firestore.

The reason I'm trying to do what I'm doing is because it is cheaper on reads, and I don't have to query the data another time.

My original approach to querying the data was like this:

in my search.ts

```
 initiateSearch() {
  if (this.searchTerm.length === 0) {
    this.queryResult = [];
    this.tempSearchStore = [];
  }
  const capitalizedsearchTerm = this.searchTerm.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + this.searchTerm.substring(1);
  if (this.queryResult.length === 0 && this.searchTerm.length === 1) {
    this.catService.searchCatalogs(this.searchTerm).then(snapShot => {
      snapShot.forEach(cat => {
        this.queryResult.push({ ...cat.data(), id: cat.id });
      });
      console.log('first', this.queryResult);
    });

  } else {
    this.tempSearchStore = [];
    this.queryResult.forEach(el => {
      if (el.name.startsWith(capitalizedsearchTerm)) {
        this.tempSearchStore.push(el);
      }
    });
    console.log('temp', this.tempSearchStore);
  }
}
```

and the service:

```
searchCats(searchFiled: string) {
    const reference = this.afs.collection('blabla');
    const query1 = reference.ref.where('searchKey', '==', 
    searchFiled.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase());
    return query1.get();
}
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you query for all documents with a string that starts with 'S', and you have [persistence enabled](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline), then the next query for documents with a string that start with 'SP' will draw its results from the cache, since what you're querying is strictly a subset of what you previously queried. You will not pay a read for each one again in that case.

Comment: Yes  i totaly agree. But that means I will have 2 querries , one in the home and one in the search component. I am trying to querry the data once only. So I am querying it and displaying all items in the home page. In the home page i have a search button, and when i click it it opens up a new modal, which means I have to querry again the data in the firestore no?.
That's why i thought i would pass the items as components props from the home to the search components, so im left with an array of object in the search component, which i would like to filter.
Again not too sure about that.

Comment: It doesn't matter what screen the query comes from.  It all uses the same persistence layer.

Comment: Yes, but here is what I am struglging with.
If lets say I querried all based on "S" that mean in that querry I have all the items with S. If i wanna do another search with a different first charachter then  that's another querry from the firestore.
So why not just querry all the documents once (in my case around 50), and then pass it to other components.
In this case, when i am filtering I am not dealing with firestore, I am just filtering the array of object.. So no matter how many different new searches i make, it is all from that array, not from the firestore, thus less reads.

Comment: Whatever you're comfortable with.  Your new question seems to be more about opinion rather than difficulty with implementation.

Comment: Its actually both. I am kind of new to Firebase and Angular, and I am looking for advice.
But I am defintley struggling with filtering an array based on the user's input.
If you have any suggestions about it, I would be more than thankful.
I was trying to create a customed Pipe to filter, but it is not working.

Comment: Filtering an array sounds like a new question that you should post separately, as this question is about the cost of document reads.

Comment: The title is about filtering an array. That was the original question, and still is :). You were so kind to explain to me and clarify the firestore part, that's why we kind of wandered from the original question.

Comment: It sounded like you had a misconception about how Firestore queries work with respect to cost and local caching.  With that new information, does that give you everything you need to move forward? If you have a new followup question that adds information, that belongs in its own post, otherwise there's no limit to how much folks will go back and forth.